# How to add a drop shadow for a SwiftUI List's Section?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, listview, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view that makes use of a `Section` view within a `List` view. What I'm trying to do is add some drop-shadow around the section so that the section's content is clearly separated from the background of the main view. However, no matter what I've tried and Googled, I cannot get a drop-shadow to show up around the entire section. For reference, the first image below is a mockup and is what I'm trying to make my code look like. The second image is an exaggerated version of my SwiftUI view to help me debug what's going on. As you can tell, there is no drop shadow showing up.

[image: Mockup Reference Image]
[image: Actual SwiftUI View]

Finally, the following is the code I have. I have tried everything that I could find, including updating the UITableView's `Appearance`; however, I think I'm updating the wrong thing. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Code:

```
struct CatalogView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CatalogViewModel

    init(viewModel: CatalogViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        UITableView.appearance().layer.masksToBounds = false
        UITableView.appearance().layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        UITableView.appearance().layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        UITableView.appearance().layer.shadowRadius = 100
        UITableView.appearance().layer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 10, height: 10)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(LocalizedStringKey("CatalogView.Program.Catalog")) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.programs) {
                        Text($0.name)
                    }
                }
                .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 25, x: 0, y: 0)
                .headerProminence(.increased)
            }
            .navigationTitle(viewModel.navigationTitle)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    PlusButton {
                        print("Hi")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
struct ContentView: View {
init() { UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear }

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Important tasks")) {
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            Section(header: Text("Main tasks")) {
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 10, x: 5, y: 5)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray4).ignoresSafeArea())
        .navigationTitle("Menu")
    }
}
```

}
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think to put the shadow on the list itself. This did the trick! The only unfortunate side-effect is that when the Section's header prominence is set to `.increased` as so: `.headerProminence(.increased)`, the shadow color is applied to the header as well. Fortunately for me, my shadow color is very subtle so you can't tell it's there. However, do you know of a way to address that as well? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your most welcome... 
You can try this answer for header shadow thing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460935/list-style-swiftui

Comment: Note that the settings the appearance this way makes it global, not only for this view.

Comment: Hello @HetaliBhimjiyani ! I've tried your answer today and I think some things may have changed, because I copied your code and it doesn't seem to work anymore, it puts a shadow around the whole list. Maybe I'm missing something. Do know about any changes in swiftui or ios that could've happened ? Thanks !

Hello to you too NirvanNagar, maybe you know something too ^^ Thanks !

Comment: Yes @AlfredWallace I also checked this code the output is different now
Let me try to figure out how to solve that

Comment: Thank you @HetaliBhimjiyani!   I've noticed than it works with the list style Plain, but then we lose the rounded edges. But it could be the basis for a workaround ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear the background color of **`UITableView`** because of **UIKit**.

```
init(viewModel: CatalogViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        ....................
}
```

Add your shadow code to outside of `List` not the outside of `Section` and then add background color to view

```
List {
       Section(LocalizedStringKey("CatalogView.Program.Catalog")) {
         ForEach(viewModel.programs) {
            Text($0.name)
         }
       }
       .headerProminence(.increased)
}
.shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 25, x: 0, y: 0) //=====> add this line for shadow 
.background(Color(UIColor.cyan).ignoresSafeArea()) //=====> add this line for background color
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! This is basically the code I needed to get it working. The only thing that is missing is the `.padding(.top, 1)` since without this line, the sections go to the top of the screen (and behind the navigation title and bar). However, one side-effect to this is that the Section's Header also gets the shadow applied to it. Do you happen to know if that can be addressed?

Comment: this does not work anymore